# When does spring use AOP without Aspectj.jar?

Tags: spring, aop, spring-aop

I can use annotation @Transactional at the top of my service PersonServiceBean and config transactionManager like below. After that, my service can execute db operations under transaction control through AOP.

```
 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource">
          .........
 </bean>
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManager"/>
 <bean id="personService" class="cn.itcast.service.impl.PersonServiceBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
 </bean>
```

[image]
But i didn't include aspectj.jar into my project. How does it work? I heard spring implements AOP through aspectj.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't use AspectJ by default, but uses proxies (either JDK interface proxies or CGLIB proxies). So, when you inject a transactional bean into another bean, what you get injected is in fact a proxy to your actual bean instance, which intercepts the method calls and starts/commits/rollbacks transactions.

More in [the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#aop-introduction-spring-defn), of course.

Comment: When does spring use aspectJ? If I use annotation @Aspect?

Comment: Follow the documentation link and read: 9.2 AspectJ support: *Using the AspectJ compiler and weaver enables use of the full AspectJ language, and is discussed in Section 9.8, “Using AspectJ with Spring applications”.*